# Flink group with time-windowed join

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Two stream as table1, table2. We know that group with regular join won't work so we have to use time-windowed join. So here is my flink sql looks like:

```
SELECT
        a.account account,
        SUM(a.value) + SUM(b.value),
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TUMBLE_START(a.producer_timestamp, INTERVAL '3' MINUTE))
FROM
        (SELECT
                account,
                value,
            producer_timestamp
        FROM
                table1) a,
        (SELECT
                account,
                value,
                producer_timestamp
        FROM
                table2) b
WHERE
        a.account = b.account AND
        a.producer_timestamp BETWEEN b.producer_timestamp - INTERVAL '3' MINUTE AND b.producer_timestamp)
group by
        a.account,
        TUMBLE(a.producer_timestamp, INTERVAL '3' MINUTE)
```

But i still got error from flink:

```
Rowtime attributes must not be in the input rows of a regular join. As a workaround you can cast the time attributes of input tables to TIMESTAMP before.
Please check the documentation for the set of currently supported SQL features.
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.runVolcanoPlanner(TableEnvironment.scala:450)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.optimizePhysicalPlan(TableEnvironment.scala:369)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.optimize(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:814)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.translate(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:860)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.writeToSink(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:344)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.insertInto(TableEnvironment.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.sqlUpdate(TableEnvironment.scala:962)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.sqlUpdate(TableEnvironment.scala:922)
....
```

I think i use time-windowed join just like this doc says:https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#time-windowed-joins. But flink told me its a regular join. Is there anything wrong i haven't notice?

Comment: Could you provide the optimized plan for this? Using `TableEnvironment.explain()`? You are right, it should not be interpreted as a regular join. But maybe the tumbling window has higher precedence.